# JVM garbage collection suddenly takes a lot of CPU

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

I have an application which reads XML-responses from a server. 
This is working nice, until I try to read ~200.000 XML-responses. When I reach that magic number, the handling time reduces with a factor 10. 
When I let it run, at some point the JVM would say that the GC is taking 90% of CPU-time. So I first tried to optimize my code - using fields instead of local variables, using intern on my strings (Since I have a lot of copies) and so on.

This helped a bit, but it still went slow after approx 100k XML-files. I then tried using Visual VM to see what was going on, and what I saw was:

[image: VisualVM Screendump]

Up until 18:02, everything works fine. Then suddenly the garbage collector is going bananas, and stealing CPU-time, which then in turn stabilizes memory consumption. I would understand this, if we we're hitting maximum memory of the heap, but I've set max heap size at 8 gb.

There is nothing different happening at that point, it's basically a giant loop doing the same thing over and over.

What is happening and what can I do in this situation?

Comment: This question is way too broad and vague. You're creating too much garbage and you need to create less garbage.

Comment: I recommend running with [JFR](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-4/jfr-runtime-guide/run.htm#JFRUH164) turned on `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,dumponexit=t‌rue,dumponexitpath=p‌​ath` or similar. Analyse the recording to see what's in memory.

Comment: My guess? You're holding onto those XML responses in memory somewhere.

Comment: Creating garbage is not necessarily the problem. Azul have shown their JVM dealing with 700 threads running on 700 cres creating 20 GiByte/s of garbage on a 500 GiByte heap without even breaking a sweat, and that was with VM and GC technology from 10 years ago. The problem is *old* garbage.

Comment: @Kayaman While I agree that reducing garbage would be a great plan, some libraries that I use, unfortuanly is a bit messy. I've tried to reduce as much as I can myself. Another question was why the garbage is not just piling up, until memory is out - why will the garbage collector gain superior CPU, when memory isn't at a critical level?

Comment: @BoristheSpider i'll give it a try. 
That's my guess too. The library that parses the XML seems to be holding onto the arrays with data. I'll give your recomendation a try :)

Comment: As @JörgWMittag says, garbage is not an issue - create as much as you want. But make sure it _becomes_ garbage. Look at the output from JFR and determine what's hanging around. It might be as simple as calling `close()` on something.

Comment: Could you please press "Perform GC" in VisualVM UI and see if the memory consumption will reduce?. Also, are you holding all the XML files in memory or what?. I think these two questions will tell us a lot about your memory consumption.

Comment: @QusaiAlothman that does not help - I've tried. I'm parsing the XML to classes, which then in turn is being parsed to XML another place. Though right now, when the XML has been parsed to a class, it's simply being left for dead (poll from list, and then just return).

Comment: In that case, i second what @BoristheSpider said. You probably forgot to close the streams or files somewhere.

Comment: Something you are doing is holding heap. I suggest you do a heap dump and analyse it to see where the memory is being consumed.  YourKit is a good tool for this, as is VisualVM (which is ok, but free)

Answer (score 2):

Your heap size is insufficient for your workflow. You may have memory leak, or it just specific of your application.

Normal pattern for parallel GC algorithm (which you have enabled)

```
Young GC
Young GC
... 
Full GC
```

Though, once old space is full (~5.6 GiB for your setup), pattern would switch to

```
Full GC
Full GC
Full GC
...
```

Full GC is order of magnitude longer, so application would stay in GC pause (with high CPU consumption) almost all time. VisialVM incorrectly charts GC CPU usage, in reality blue spikes are as high as orange line on CPU chart.

If memory usage grows due to memory leak, you should address that.

If it is application design specific, you need increase old space by

- either increasing total heap size
- or reducing young space (`-Xmn=SIZE` option) to save more memory for old space